# Why do hyperlinks stop working when writing large spreadsheets with POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using POI 3.9 and SXSSF to create spreadsheets. When there are a small number of rows, creating hyperlinks works. However, as the size grows the processing time greatly increases and the links do not work. It works for 700 rows but not 70,000. When trying to open the file, this error occurs:

Excel found unreadable content in 'out.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    Workbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); // keep 100 rows in memory, exceeding rows will be flushed to disk
    Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();
    for(int rownum = 0; rownum < 70000; rownum++){
        Row row = sh.createRow(rownum);
        for(int cellnum = 0; cellnum < 10; cellnum++){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum);
            String address = new CellReference(cell).formatAsString();
            cell.setCellValue(address);
            if (address.contains("A"))
                setHyperlink(cell, address);
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:/temp/sxssf.xlsx");
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
}

protected static void setHyperlink(Cell cell, String address) {
    Workbook workbook = cell.getSheet().getWorkbook();
    Hyperlink hyperlink = workbook.getCreationHelper()
            .createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_URL);
    String encoded = null;
    try {
        encoded = URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    hyperlink.setAddress(encoded);
    cell.setHyperlink(hyperlink);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the maximum number of hyperlinks on a excel is limited to 65,530.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3